# Output custom author fields on entry

Tags: members, custom-fields

I'm trying to output a custom field of the author of an entry. And no matter what I do, it wraps it in an `<a>` tag that I cannot do anything with. I just want to output that value, but ExpressionEngine keeps wrapping it.

All I do is this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="mychannel"}
    {custom_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And what comes out is this:

```
<a href="whatever is in this field">whatever is in this field</a>
```

And if I try to wrap it in an a tag myself, it wraps double.

```
<a href="<a href="whatever is in this field"></a>">Link here</a>
```

Do I really need to strip the output manually with either PHP or Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the "auto hyperlink" feature built into each of the Channel preferences. This custom field doesn't happen to be a hyperlink or email address by chance?

If it is, simply disable this feature on a per channel basis by:

1. going to Admin > Channels > Edit Preferences (for whatever channel you want to edit),
2. Scroll down and set "Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links" to NO.

--

You can also explore whether the custom field has a certain **Default Text Formatting** setting that's causing it to format differently on publish.

1. Admin > Channel Fields
2. Click into a Group
3. Edit the field settings
4. Set **Default Text Formatting** to **no**